# React-Native-fbsdk read and publish

Tags: facebook, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I use react-native-fbsdk to login my users into my application like that :

```
 LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile", "email", "user_birthday", "user_location", "user_about_me"])
```

But i need to permit to my users to share some informations to their facebook feed ! So i need to have 'publish_actions' permissions and it's not working with 'logInWithReadPermissions' and, i can't set read permissions with 'logInWithPublishPermissions' !

So how can i do that ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `logInWithPublishPermissions` function too: https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/blob/master/js/FBLoginManager.js

...although, you should consider using the Share Dialog, it does not need `publish_actions`: https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk

Make sure you don´t ask for read and write permissions at the same time, you only need write permissions just before the user wants to share something anyway, not when he logs in.